# The closure of certain subspace of $\ell_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, cesaro-summable

What is the  closure of the following subspace $A$ of $\ell_\infty$  with the standard sup norm of $\ell_\infty$:

$$A=\{(a_n)\in \ell_\infty\mid (A_n)=a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n\; \text{belongs to} \;\ell_\infty \}$$

Is it true to say that $\bar{A}$ is the space of  all $(a_n)\in \ell_\infty$ such that the  Cesaro sum $\frac{a_1+a_2 +\ldots +a_n}{n}$  goes to zero?

If it is the case, what is a proof?

Comment: Hint: think about the case $a_1+\cdots+a_n=\sqrt n$.

Comment: @David, your sequence is in $c_0$ and hence also in $\bar A$.

Comment: nice! question without effort to solve it not being downvoted or closed just because the topic is not "basic"

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich . Or (similarly) if $a_n=1/\sqrt n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the linear map
$
  T :\ell ^\infty \to \ell ^\infty ,
  $
given by $T ((s_n)_{n\geq 1}) = (a_n)_{n\geq 1}$,  where
$$
  a_n =
  \left\{\matrix{
    s_1, & \text{if } n=1,\hfill\cr
    s_n-s_{n-1}, & \text{otherwise },
    }\right.
  $$
and observe that $A$ is precisely the range of $T $.

Moreover, observe that $T =I-S$, where $S$ is the right shift on $\ell ^\infty $.

For a continuous linear functional $f$ on $\ell ^\infty $ one then has that $f$ vanishes on $A$ if and only if $f =f\circ S$.

The answer is then that $\bar A$ coincides with the intersection of the kernels of all right-invariant linear functionals
on $\ell ^\infty $.

Comment: I must admit that Ryszard's deleted answer helped a lot!

Comment: Nice. I have deleted my answer as I thought for a while  that the space indicated in the question gives the correct answer. But it seems that this space is larger, which means that the condition $(a_1+\ldots +a_n)/n\to 0$ does not imply $f(\{a_n\})=0$ for any right invariant functional.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting answer.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you very much for your attention to my question and your help on this post.

Comment: I vaguly remember there is a terminology for this kernel, when I was learning BLF (Banach limit functional). Am i right?

Comment: Credits are due to @Ruy for a very clear reasoning. Besides I would be interested in a proof that the closed subspace indicated by OP is larger than the intersection of the kernels of invariant functionals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The closure is the space of sequences that are [almost convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_convergent_sequence) to zero. See Theorem 3(i) of *Bennett, G.; Kalton, N. J.*, [**Consistency theorems for almost convergence**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1996745), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 198, 23-43 (1974). [ZBL0301.46005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0301.46005). It is not sufficient that the Cesàro sum to is zero: a random $\pm1$-valued sequence has zero Cesàro sum but is not almost convergent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Thank you again for your very helpful answer I am sorry ican not accept two answer at the same time.